# Android Mixing Audio Input

Tags: android, audio, media

I've read a lot of questions on stackoverflow and other pages about this topic, but didn't find a real up-to-date solution:

In an Android-App I've got two audio files (local file system), which are encoded in mp3, ogg or wav.
I just want to play them exactly synchronously, have seeking possibilities and control the volume of each single track. Using MediaPlayer this isn't possible because of the well known latency issues in Android.
So I think having two Audio-Player-Instances (of whatever library) will allways result in bad latencies, so it seems not to be the solution.

So in my opinion the only solution would be to mix together the audio inputs to a somewhat mixed input, which can be played by one Player. I read a lot about Androids AudioTrack and buffers and the OpenSL ES implementation, but allways ended with the notice: buffers only support PCM raw audio data. Ok, so I have to decode the mp3/ogg by myself?

My Question now is: Is there any library that can help me to a) do exactly what I want with a simple API or b) decode mp3/ogg to memory to use that data with AudioTrack or OpenSL?

If it's native or Java is unimportant, it just has to work.
The minimum API-Level is 15+ (Android 4.0.3, most current Version while creating this question).